# "Connection cannot be null when hibernate.dialect is not set" and sessionFactory error

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-security, tomcat8

I want to import in eclipse and connect with PostgreSQL database. PostgreSQL is configured on another machine.

I have imported the war file in eclipse and changed 3 file with IP address of the machine where PostgreSQL is installed. Three files were hibernate.cnf.xml, spring-database.xml, na-dispatcher.xml.  Like

```
jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.15:5432/mydatabase.
```

After that I tried running the application in tomcat server with eclipse IDE.

I got error like

> ./web-inf/sping-security.xml

## 1

> Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Also an error regarding session factory and all.
I can't paste the code because we can't use internet in office. Please help me in resolving this. Tomorrow is the deadline. `no code`

## 2

> Error creating bean with name ‘sessionFactory’ defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when ‘hibernate.dialect’ not set

Comment: is there any other file that i have to change the database ip address?

Comment: Hi Anu, I think there is a problem in your dialect configuration. could you please share your  hibernate.cnf.xml file. Could you please try with this dialect <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

Comment: Changing URL alone is not enough to connect to postgre SQL you should also use proper dialect.

Comment: i am new to hibernate. i will  check the the property. I don't have the access to net in office hours and i cant move my code from the office by any method. that is the draw back because of that i am not able to get the help

Comment: what should i use in proper dialect please help me. tomorrow is the deadline.

Comment: any one please help me

Comment: I have already shared the dialect to you.please check my first comment mostly it will work.please share the stack trace if there is any issue

Comment: If there is still an issue ...please share your hibernate.cnf.xml...so that we can fix the session factory issue

Comment: thank you.i will do the same

Comment: should i have to do any thing in postgresql server?

Comment: Nothing ... Just modify the dialect and try